# Snake javascript, moving up and down, makes the block bigger than 5px

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is jsfiddle sample - http://jsfiddle.net/6bKHc/120/ and code -

```
    var move, inter;
    inter = setInterval(move = function() {
        var dir = $(".snake").data('dir');
        var snake = $('.snake');
        var food = $('.food');
        if(dir == 'top') {
            snake.css({"top": snake.position().top + 5 + "px"});
            if(snake.width() > 5) {
                snake.css({"width": snake.width() - 5 + "px", "height": snake.height() + 5 + "px"});   
            }
        }
        if(dir == 'bottom') {
            snake.css({"top": snake.position().top - 5 + "px"});
            if(snake.width() > 5) {
                snake.css({"width": snake.width() - 5 + "px", "height": snake.height() + 5 + "px"});   
            }            
        }
        if(dir == 'left') {
            snake.css({"left": snake.position().left + 5 + "px"});
            if(snake.height() > 5) {
                snake.css({"width": snake.width() + 5 + "px", "height": snake.height() - 5 + "px"});   
            }            
        }
        if(dir == 'right') {
            snake.css({"left": snake.position().left - 5 + "px"});
            if(snake.height() > 5) {
                snake.css({"width": snake.width() + 5 + "px", "height": snake.height() - 5 + "px"});   
            }              
        }
        var snakePosition = snake.position();
        var foodPosition = food.position();
        var randomNum = Math.ceil(Math.random()*40);
        var randomNumber = randomNum*5;
        console.log(snakePosition.top + " - snake top + left - " + snakePosition.left);
        console.log(foodPosition.top + " - snake top + left - " + foodPosition.left);        
        if(snakePosition.top == foodPosition.top && snakePosition.left == foodPosition.left) {
            console.log(randomNumber);
            snake.css({"width": snake.width() + 55 + "px"});   
            food.css({"left": randomNumber+1+"px", "top": randomNumber+1+"px"});            
        }
    }, 200);
$(document).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.which == 40) {
        $(".snake").data('dir','top');
    } else if(event.which == 39) {
        $(".snake").data('dir','left');           
    } else if(event.which == 37) {
        $(".snake").data('dir','right');        
    } else if(event.which == 38) {
        $(".snake").data('dir','bottom');    
    };     
});​
```

When snakes gets bigger, it automatically makes the block also bigger, I mean when you move down it won't stay 5px in one side. I'm not sure how to describe it, but just start the game and try eating food and then moving, you will se what I mean.

Comment: (offtopic) I like it this way! :) looks more like a *Blob* game!

Comment: Upvoted all of your cool answers :)! Will accept one later.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/b2rg4/  maybe some reference will help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I'm guessing you're trying to make a Nokia style snake game here, you cant do it with a single Div because it can only be a rectangle; you are going to have to use an array of Divs (if you want to use the method you are using here) and update their position one by one in a loop.

I'll add a code sample after work if you haven't managed to figure it out.

**EDIT::**

Ok, I've made some modifications to your code so you have have a tail on your snake now, the full code is as follows (Explication below):

```
    var move, inter;
    var snakeBody= [];

    // Main Loop
    inter = setInterval(move = function() {
        var dir = $(".snake").data('dir');
        var snake = $('.snake');
        var food = $('.food');

        // Update body segment positions
        for (bodySeg=snakeBody.length-1;bodySeg>=0;bodySeg--){
            var lastsegment;
            if (bodySeg==0) {lastsegment=snake;} else {lastsegment=snakeBody[bodySeg-1];}

            snakeBody[bodySeg].css({"top": lastsegment.position().top});
            snakeBody[bodySeg].css({"left": lastsegment.position().left});                
        }

        // update head of the snake, depending on last pressed key
        if(dir == 'top') {
            snake.css({"top": snake.position().top + 5 + "px"});
        } 
        if(dir == 'bottom') {
            snake.css({"top": snake.position().top - 5 + "px"});          
        }
        if(dir == 'left') {
            snake.css({"left": snake.position().left + 5 + "px"});           
        }
        if(dir == 'right') {
            snake.css({"left": snake.position().left - 5 + "px"});             
        }



        // Handle Head of snake touching food
        var snakePosition = snake.position();
        var foodPosition = food.position();
        var randomNum = Math.ceil(Math.random()*40);
        var randomNumber = randomNum*5;       
        if(snakePosition.top == foodPosition.top && snakePosition.left == foodPosition.left) {
            var index = snakeBody.length;
            $("#content").append("<div id='snakebody"+index+"' class='snakebodycss'></div>");
            snakeBody[index]=$("#snakebody"+index);
            food.css({"left": randomNumber+1+"px", "top": randomNumber+1+"px"});            
        }
    }, 200);
// update last pressed key
$(document).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.which == 40) {
        $(".snake").data('dir','top');
    } else if(event.which == 39) {
        $(".snake").data('dir','left');           
    } else if(event.which == 37) {
        $(".snake").data('dir','right');        
    } else if(event.which == 38) {
        $(".snake").data('dir','bottom');    
    } else if(event.which == 13) {
        console.log(snakeBody)
    }        
});​
```

The Html has not changed:

```
<div id="content">
 <div class="snake">
 </div>
 <div class="food">
 </div>
</div>​
```

I've added another css class for the body segments:

```
#content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  float: left;    
}

#content .snake {
  background: green;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;  
  z-index: 10;
}

#content .snakebodycss {
  background: red;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;  
  z-index: 10;
}

#content .food {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: orange;  
  position: absolute;    
}
```

---

Explanations:

​

Ok, maybe this will help, I've modified your code so it now has an array called `snakeBody[]` which is keeping track of the new segments in the snake, if you look at the new for loop:

```
   // This for loop will run through the snakeBody array backwards, from the highest index to 0
   // This is to allow us to set each segment to the location of the next closest to the head 
   // each loop
   for (bodySeg=snakeBody.length-1;bodySeg>=0;bodySeg--){
        //We need a reference the the previous segment to set the one we are currently inspecting
        // It will either be another segment or the head of the snake
        var lastsegment;
        if (bodySeg==0) {lastsegment=snake;} else {lastsegment=snakeBody[bodySeg-1];}

        snakeBody[bodySeg].css({"top": lastsegment.position().top});
        snakeBody[bodySeg].css({"left": lastsegment.position().left});                
    }
```

This is what is updating the tail positions each loop to the next position.

```
   if(snakePosition.top == foodPosition.top && snakePosition.left == foodPosition.left) {
        // Here we get the top position (unoccupied) of our snake body array
        var index = snakeBody.length;
        // Here we are adding a new div to the content div, with a unique id (snakevody0)
        // (snakebody1) etc etc 
        $("#content").append("<div id='snakebody"+index+"' class='snakebodycss'></div>");
        // Here we are populating the array we use in the above for loop with refrences
        // to our snake segment divs.
        snakeBody[index]=$("#snakebody"+index);
        food.css({"left": randomNumber+1+"px", "top": randomNumber+1+"px"});            
    }
```

And that is attaching the bodysegnts to the DOM and storing their references in the array for later use.

If you're having any trouble with this let me know.

Comment: Hello, Okay thanks! I will try to deal with it meanwhile also ;)!

Comment: Ok, I've added an Example now; let me know how you get on!

Comment: Okay, I will try to create it myself, so I can understand this feature. I will accept your answer as best one! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is not a simple one.  You shouldn't be altering the height and width of the snake when it's changing direction, you need to create a second snake tail which decreases in size as you increase the first snake tail in length.  So if you are going left, and you press down, create a new snake tail which is one unit big, travelling downwards, then decrease old tail by 1 unit, increase new tail by one unit downwards, and decrease old tail by one unit widthwards etc...

This process may be neeeded to be kept track of for several individual tail parts, you may change direction several times within one length of your snake.

Comment: Hey, thanks for idea! Any other cool ideas to add to this blob type game?

Comment: Edges - need to have edge detection (And collision detection for crossing the snakes own tail, but I imagine you've thought of this?)

Comment: Yup! Will add it in next releases :D

Answer (score 1):

I assume your question is "Why doesn't my snake look like a regular snake from other snake-related games?". To make a snake, it can't only have one position (snakePosition). A snake normally consists of several parts. How are you going to keep track of where the snake bends?

Comment: Hey, yes that's correct :)! Any other cool ideas to add to this blob type game?

Comment: You could use elipses instead of rectangles, add different morph shapes, different colors, make it multiplayer, add particle effects and fade in/out etc. However, basing the game on interesting gameplay may be a better start than basing it on unintended side-effects. ;)